# uploading video to facebook error 2

Tags: facebook, video, upload

I am trying to upload a video taken with my iphone app to Facebook.

In my app's .plist I have added

FacebookAppId, FacebookDisplayName, URLSchemes and I have registered my app with Facebook developer.

In the iPhone settings, my app is allowed to use Facebook account

Then I allow my user to title the video and give a description of it and then upload it to Facebook by tapping a button.

```
 - (void)buttonRequestClickHandler:(id)sender {

        if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
  //this is the path to the video          
            NSString *audioName = [pictureDictionary4 objectForKey:@"photoVideokey"];
            NSArray *pathsa = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectorya = [pathsa objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *moviePath = [documentsDirectorya stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Movie"];
            NSString *fullPatha = [moviePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:audioName];

NSURL *pathURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:fullPatha isDirectory:NO];
            NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPatha];

//these are the title and description of the video
NSString *titleString = self.videotitle.text;
            NSString *descripString = self.descrp.text;

            NSDictionary *videoObject = @{
                                          @"title":titleString,
                                          @"description": descripString,
                                          [pathURL absoluteString]: videoData
                                          };
            FBRequest *uploadRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                            parameters:videoObject
                                                            HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

           [uploadRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if (!error)
                    NSLog(@"Done: %@", result);
                else
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);}];
        }
```

**this is where I get the error  The operation couldn't be completed.(com.facebook.sdk error 2.)
so apparently I am not getting a session from the appDelegate and no login here either.**

```
 else {
permissions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_streams",nil];

  [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
  defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
  allowLoginUI:YES
  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
  FBSessionState status,
  NSError *error) {
  // if login fails for any reason, we alert THIS IS THE ERROR I GET
  if (error) {
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
    message:error.localizedDescription
    delegate:nil
    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];




    // if otherwise we check to see if the session is open, an alternative to
    // to the FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE helper-macro would be to check the isOpen
    // property of the session object; the macros are useful, however, for more
    // detailed state checking for FBSession objects
    } else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status)) {
    // send our requests if we successfully logged in

    NSString *audioName = [pictureDictionary4 objectForKey:@"photoVideokey"];
    NSArray *pathsa = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectorya = [pathsa objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *moviePath = [documentsDirectorya stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Movie"];
    NSString *fullPatha = [moviePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:audioName];

    NSString *titleString = self.videotitle.text;
    NSString *descripString = self.descrp.text;

    NSURL *pathURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:fullPatha isDirectory:NO];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPatha];

    NSDictionary *videoObject = @{
                                   @"title":titleString,
                                   @"description": descripString,
                                   [pathURL absoluteString]: videoData};
    FBRequest *uploadRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                                 parameters:videoObject
                                                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [uploadRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                      if (!error)
                      NSLog(@"Done: %@", result);
      else
                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);}];
                                              }}];
        }}
```

Can anyone see where I have done something wrong with the log in for a session?

I would greatly appreciate anyone help with this.

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Comment: in a way it is related to xcode since I am trying to integrate the facebook video upload into an iphone app written using Xcode

Comment: @userXXX Well, would you consider the problem different if you used Eclipse instead? Or `emacs` and `make`? I doubt.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed things around a bit.  I am using code from HelloFacebookSample app to make sure I am logged in and I no longer get the error 2.  The debugger shows that the video starts to upload as it shows the NSLog for VideoData.  However after a while the data Stream starts to show 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 and then maybe some with something like 6d766578 00000020 for a while then back to zeros again with increasing frequency.  Then finally it errors out with
2013-06-27 22:50:14.407 my little world app[8145:907] Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
not sure what this means but will post another question.